# Why are my client-side javascript breakpoints not being hit?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, javascript-debugger

I'm setting forth on my first Single-Page Application.  I've installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional with Update 2, and loaded the project.  I've gone into IE10 and unchecked the "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)" checkbox.

Here's my code snippet that **ought** to be hit by the debugger

[image]

However, when I run the code the red breakpoint symbol turns to a hollow white one

[image]

with the legend "*The breakpoint will not currently be hit; no symbols have been loaded for this document*".

I'm at a loss here.  Even the debugger; statement isn't causing the code to break out.

I've reinstalled VS2012 and Update 2 twice now.

Thanks

Edward

Comment: UPDATE:  I've reverted back from IE10 to IE9 and now have a different problem.  The breakpoints are still not being hit (No symbols have been loaded for this document) but the debugger; statement is now causing the code to stop with "An unhandled exception ('Script Breakpoint') occurred in iexplorer.exe".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multipel projects in your solution, is the file where you are putting breakpoint belongs to same project that is set as start up project?

Comment: Yes, there are three projects but, the file containing the breakpoint is the one set as startup project.  In fact there are several breakpoints, none of which is being hit (which I know because of the various operations underway).

Comment: you need to restart IE and VS aftre you have enabled script debugging, also are you able to hit the first line of your program start, can you try putting breakpoint there and step through to see how far you can reach?

Comment: I've restarted IE and VS multiple times as well as at least five reboots (and done numerous iisreset operations).  I can hit breakpoints in the data layer (C# code) but not in any javascript.

Comment: Are you attaching VS to the process, WebBrowserServer.exe?

Comment: No, I'm not attaching VS to the process, but according to the colleagues sitting either side of me, working on the same codebase in the same dev environment, this is not necessary.  Nor have I found it necessary in debugging javascript in previous flavours of VS - the debugger statement normally works if client-side debugging is enabled in IE.

Comment: Try running Page inspector in VS, and when JAVA error dialog opens select No, that should most likely work, more details, refer this page http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/hands-on-labs/using-page-inspector-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Page Inspector not useful.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to give the function a name (openMain function name here)
Just to make it a bit more understandable I'll show a code that I used for a site.

```
<form  name="myForm" action="mailto:kkatsman@rocfriesepoort.nl?subject=Stickers" enctype="text/plain" method="POST" onsubmit=" return formcheck()">
        <table id="formulier">
            <tr>
                <td>Klas:</td>              <td><input type="text" required name="klas" id="klas" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Examencode:</td>        <td><input type="text" required name="examencode" id="examencode" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Examennaam:</td>        <td><input type="text" required name="examennaam" id="examennaam" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Datum:</td>             <td><input type="text" required name="datum" id="datum" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>                   
                <td>Week:</td>              <td><input type="text" required name="week" id="week" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Tijdstip: van</td>      <td><input type="text" required name="van" id="van"  onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>   <td>tot</td>    <td><input type="text" required name="tot" id="tot" onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
                <td>Docent:</td>            <td><input type="text" required name="docent" id="docent"  onkeyup="vulaan(this)"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So when there is a keypressed in a certain textbox it refers to the function "vulaan"

now my javascript file looks something like:

```
function vulaan()
{
    //voor de klas
    var klas = document.getElementById('klas').value;
    var klas1 = document.getElementById('klas1').value;
    var klas2 = document.getElementById('klas2').value;

    document.getElementById('klas1').value = klas;
    document.getElementById('klas2').value = klas;
}
```

Comment: well when i make a site and I use javascript I give each funtion a name. like when I make a contact form or some sort I can do a check with javascrtipt by doing something like:
a onlick="name" and that "name"refers to a function called name

Comment: Thanks user1879621 - I'll take a look tomorrow and revert.